# Is there a solution to prevent bfcdownload() function from continuously asking to overwrite existing files in R console?

Tags: r, userscripts

After executing this code

```
pkgsList <- list()
for (i in 1:length(packageNames)) {
  if (packageNames[[i]] %in% pckgs) {
    rank <- pkgDownloadRank(packageNames[[i]], "software", version)
    pkgsList[[i]] <- list(package = packageNames[[i]],
                          rank = rank[[1]],
                          priority = ifelse(rank[[1]] < threshold, "High", "Low"),
                          status = ifelse(packageNames[[i]] %in% coreMaintained, "To do", "Contact maintainer"))
  } else {
    pkgsList[[i]] <- list(package = packageNames[[i]],
                          rank = " ",
                          priority = " ",
                          status = "Deprecated")
  }
}
```

again and again getting this option:

```
bfcdownload() will overwrite exisiting files, continue? (yes/no): yes
                                                                                                  |==================================================================================================================================================| 100%

bfcdownload() will overwrite exisiting files, continue? (yes/no):
```

Anyone have the solution for this ?

I have tried executing this code in R console..

I expect to get a excel sheet with rank of vignettes after executing this code and 2 more additional line of code.

```
# Convert the list to a dataframe
dataframe <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, pkgsList))

# Final output as an excel file
write.xlsx(dataframe, output_file, col_names= TRUE)
```